# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard, tried pip3 install, tried -pip list it is there

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, python-module

Some extra info:
I am on Windows 10, using latest Python version, using latest pip version, using Pycharm as my IDE. I am making a keylogger program for a project and I cannot seem to get keyboard module working.

Also:
C:\Users\Hp>pip --version
pip 20.2.2 from c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

C:\Users\Hp>pip install keyboard
Requirement already satisfied: keyboard in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (0.13.5)

C:\Users\Hp>pip list
Package        Version

---

altgraph       0.17
future         0.18.2
keyboard       0.13.5
pefile         2019.4.18
pip            20.2.2
PyInstaller    3.6
pywin32-ctypes 0.2.0
setuptools     41.2.0

The error message in PyCharm: C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\keylogger\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Hp/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/keylog.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Hp/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/keylog.py", line 2, in 
import keyboard
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard'

Comment: your project in PyCharm is using virtualenv ( `Users\Hp\Desktop\keylogger\venv\Scripts\python.exe` <- venv path )  while the `keyboard` package is installed into a global site-packages ( `users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32` ).

Answer (score 1):

- 1. Activate your virtual-environment

---

- ```sh
  .\env\Scripts\activate
  ```

  or

  ```sh
  C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\keylogger\venv\Scripts\activate
  ```
- 2. Now install `keyboard`

---

- ```sh
  pip install keyboard
  ```

@yedpodtrzitko already answered, I just want to make it clearer with solution-steps.